# Can I store duplicated strings in a string array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, duplicates

In my Android app I have a `String[]`.

If I have 2 of the same Strings, like:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc";
```

Can I store both Strings `a` and `b` in the same `String[]`?

Comment: did you try to do it ?

Comment: Yes, you can store them both in the same array.  But keep in mind, both strings might be backed by the same entry in the pool.  I think you are confusing sets and arrays.  In the former, you could only have one such entry.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem and you're wondering if this is the cause. Just post the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: @weston I don't have a problem. I've just wanted to know

Comment: There is no issue. You can add duplicate string into an array.

Comment: `String[] array = { "abc", "abc", "abc" };` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the same string text to two entries in a string array.

`String[0] = "abc"` and 
`String[1] = "abc"`are perfectly fine